# How to get login from GitHub with octokit?

Tags: c#, authentication, github, oauth, token

I tried to get login name by passing token in my application. But don't know how to do that properly. Please help with this issue.

```
Console.WriteLine("Input your token: ");
string? inputToken = Console.ReadLine();

var gitHubClient = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("MyCoolFilesManager"));
    gitHubClient.Credentials = new Credentials(inputToken);

var login = gitHubClient.User.Current();
Console.WriteLine(login);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `gitHubClient.User.Current()` returns a Task object. You should use the **await** keyword to get the actual info you are looking for

```
var login = await gitHubClient.User.Current();
```